# FeathersJS authentication deactivate user

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am using FeathersJS and been happy with authentication it provides. I this case it is local JWT. A client requested user management with an ability to disable some. There is field `isDisabled` in Users model, but it's hard to figure out where the check should be performed and how to set it up.

`"@feathersjs/feathers": "^3.0.2",
"@feathersjs/authentication": "^2.1.0",
"@feathersjs/authentication-jwt": "^1.0.1",
"@feathersjs/authentication-local": "^1.0.2",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you want to check. You can either [customize the JWT verifier](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/jwt.html#customizing-the-verifier) or create a [hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) on the users service for the `get` method:

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  after: {
    get(context) {
      const user = context.result;

      if(user.isDisabled) {
        throw new Error('This user has been disabled');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Daff. Used custom verifier. Worked as a charm, but a bit tricky to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I did this directly in my authenticate hook:

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks
const { NotAuthenticated } = require('@feathersjs/errors')

const verifyIdentity = authenticate('jwt')

function hasToken(hook) {
  if (hook.params.headers == undefined) return false
  if (hook.data.accessToken == undefined) return false
  return hook.params.headers.authorization || hook.data.accessToken
}

module.exports = async function authenticate(context) {
  try {
    await verifyIdentity(context)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof NotAuthenticated && !hasToken(context)) {
      return context
    }
  }
  if (context.params.user && context.params.user.disabled) {
    throw new Error('This user has been disabled')
  }
  return context
}
```

You see I did check the just loaded user record and throw an error in case. And as this hook is called in `before:all` the user is rejected before any action is done.

Answer (score 1):

As for feathers 4 you can extend your auth strategies very easily. For example if we want to user only be able to login and verify their JWT we would do the following in authentication.ts (Typescript):

```
import { Id, Query, ServiceAddons } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication';
import { LocalStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication-local';
import { expressOauth } from '@feathersjs/authentication-oauth';

import { Application } from './declarations';

declare module './declarations' {
  interface ServiceTypes {
    'authentication': AuthenticationService & ServiceAddons<any>;
  }
}
```

Extend the local strategy by alter `getEntityQuery` to only inlcude users which are active.

```
class CustomLocalStrategy extends LocalStrategy {
  async getEntityQuery(query: Query) {
    return {
      ...query,
      active: true,
      $limit: 1
    };
  }
}
```

Extend the JWT strategy by alter `getEntity()` to return null if the user is inactive

```
class CustomJWTStrategy extends JWTStrategy {
  async getEntity(id: Id) {
    const entity = await this.entityService.get(id);

    if (!entity.active) {
      return null;
    }

    return entity;
  }
}

export default function(app: Application): void {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new CustomJWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new CustomLocalStrategy());

  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
}
```